# Why do I get an "invalid zone in SetDate" error when using Date::Manip?

Tags: perl

I have some code that I'm running with Perl 5.20 on Debian 8.1. But I'm getting a warning and an error in the following line:

```
Date::Manip::DM6::Date_Init("TZ=+0430");
```

Warning:

```
WARNING: the TZ Date::Manip config variable is deprecated
         and will be removed in March 2016.  Please use
         the SetDate or ForceDate config variables instead.
```

Error:

```
ERROR: [config_var] invalid zone in SetDate:
 at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Date/Manip/TZ.pm line 1768.
        Date::Manip::TZ::_config_var_setdate(Date::Manip::TZ=HASH(0x3a11d80), "now,+0430", 0) called at     /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Date/Manip/TZ.pm line 1641
        Date::Manip::TZ::_config_var_tz(Date::Manip::TZ=HASH(0x3a11d80), "tz", "+0430") called at           /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Date/Manip/TZ_Base.pm line 41
        Date::Manip::TZ_Base::_config_var(Date::Manip::TZ=HASH(0x3a11d80), "TZ", "+0430") called at         /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Date/Manip/Obj.pm line 250
        Date::Manip::Obj::config(Date::Manip::Date=HASH(0x3a119f0), "TZ", "+0430") called at                /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Date/Manip/DM6.pm line 96
        Date::Manip::DM6::Date_Init("TZ=+0430") called at adsl.pl line 75
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Strange that you should get that error from a simple string assignment.. Maybe you should show some more of your code, the error could be on the line above for example?

Comment: @Håkon Hægland The script has 300 lines, It is a part of it that has the error occured

Comment: It seems like you are using a deprecated config variable `TZ` and also an invalid time zone : `Date::Manip::DM6::Date_Init("TZ=+0430")`

Comment: I am PHP expert and have not worked on Perl yet, because of the system upgrading I also had to solve the problem.

Comment: @HåkonHægland How should I replace it?

Comment: I am not sure.. all I can say is that the error is [on line 1768 in Date::Manip::TZ.pm](https://metacpan.org/source/SBECK/Date-Manip-6.50/lib/Date/Manip/TZ.pm#L1768) and it caused by `__zone()` at [line 829](https://metacpan.org/source/SBECK/Date-Manip-6.50/lib/Date/Manip/TZ.pm#L829) returning the empty string.. Sorry, but I am not familiar with `Date::Manip`..

Comment: See also [Date::Manip::Migration5to6](https://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Manip::Migration5to6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The deprecation is explained in [`Date::Manip::Config`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Manip::Config#TZ):

> **TZ**
>
> This variable is deprecated, but will be supported for several releases. The `SetDate` or `ForceDate` variables (described next) should be used instead.
>
> The following are equivalent:
>
> ```
> $date->config("tz","Europe/Rome");
> $date->config("setdate","now,Europe/Rome");
> ```

As for the warning about "invalid zone," apparently* `Date::Manip` requires you to specify offsets in the format `+HH:MM:SS` (or `-HH:MM:SS`).

To fix both warnings, change line 75 of adsl.pl from this:

```
Date_Init("TZ=+0430");
```

to this:

```
Date_Init("setdate=now,+04:30:00");
```

---

* I don't see this documented anywhere, but the warning is triggered by the following code in [`Date::Manip::TZ`](https://metacpan.org/source/SBECK/Date-Manip-6.50/lib/Date/Manip/TZ.pm#L910):

```
return undef  if (! exists $$self{'data'}{'Offmod'}{$offset});
```

This does a hash lookup in [`%Date::Manip::Zones::Offmod`](https://metacpan.org/source/SBECK/Date-Manip-6.50/lib/Date/Manip/Zones.pm#L2918), which only has keys in the format `+HH:MM:SS` (or `-HH:MM:SS`).